# Configuring WiFi Proxy Settings

Tags: wi-fi, proxy

Where can I find the WiFi proxy settings?  I have the Motorola Electrify M with Android 4.1.2.  I would have expected the proxy settings to be under the advanced WiFi options, but they're not there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Long tap on the network you want to configure. Then select 'modify network'. Scroll down and check ' show advanced settings'

Comment: Keep in mind this is not available before ICS (just to mention it for other readers). +1 from me, I didn't discover that yet -- good hint!

Comment: @Izzy I found out about that here:http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649770

Comment: @JasjeevSingh Thanks for the link, too! I just cannot upvote again, so +1 to your comment :)