# How to debug an Android app's network traffic?

Tags: applications

I'm trying to listen in on the network traffic of a commercial app I've downloaded.

Ideally, I'd like the traffic to use my development machine as a proxy, where I'll have Burp or Fiddler waiting to forward requests to the web while I watch the traffic.

Is this possible with android apps? The app does not have the debugging flag set, of course. I've done no android development, so apologies in advance.

Comment: It would take a bit of work, but you could always set up your own VPN host. Then connect to it from the phone, and you'll get all network traffic, whether the phone goes through wifi or cellular. From there, you can MITM the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proxy is a proxy. Unless the app is doing compression or some other protocol like Google Chrome you should be able to observe the HTTP traffic. HTTPS traffic will require certificate for man-in-the-middle to work.

Edit 1:

On the phone/tablet go into Settings->Wi-Fi. Long press on the connection to your Wi-Fi Access point and a menu should popup to modify the connection. Once that screen comes up look for 'Advanced Options', enable and you should now be able to set manual proxy.

When I refer to Chrome I meant their data compression option for Chrome for Mobile:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression

You'll have to turn this off to sniff traffic from Chrome.

Comment: As far as I understand, the app in the phone goes straight to the router, and then into the great beyond. How do I set up either the app or the whole phone to route through another machine? How do I setup a man in the middle with a phone?

Comment: Or are you referring to this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging (I just found this and am reading through it now)

Comment: If my instructions aren't clear: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39636/configuring-wifi-proxy-settings