# Difficulty in accessing Internet through University network [require proxy setting]

Tags: wi-fi, whatsapp-messenger, proxy, asus-zenfone-2

I use university's wifi network for accessing internet. When I connect to internet from Academic area, some of the apps does not connect (especially whatsapp), whereas when I connect to internet from residential area all of apps works fine.

The network requires prxoy settings and authentication. A few of my friends uses ProxyDroid app for accessing internet which requires to root the device and I would not prefer that. Other option include running a Python script through SL4A. Any suggestions?

I am using Zenfone Laser 550kl working on ZenUI.
Thanks

Comment: Probably you need to consult with your university's IT department to set-up this correctly. Otherwise, bypassing it can be considered as "breaking rule". (it's probably blocked to avoid cheating on exams)

Comment: your point would be correct if all android users face the same restriction, but this is not the case many are using whatsapp without any additional program.

Comment: Related: [Configuring Wifi Proxy Settings](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39636/46168)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Psiphon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.psiphon3) available on Google play. Doesn't require root.
It's a proxy server, and bypasses filters in my college.
Try it out.

Comment: Link to the app, brief description?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.psiphon3&hl=en

Comment: It's a proxy server, and bypasses filters in my college

Comment: Just an update, apparently when using this app one cannot detect which apps are using internet. Hence even 'blocked' apps can have internet access. All internet appears to have been used by the Psiphon itself, and not by the app.